# Organizing the items in a binary tree

Tags: python

I need your help to organise my **Binary Search Tree**, the question say to mount and organise the tree like this:

( 11  ()  () )

( 11  ( 2  ()  () )  () )

( 11  ( 2  ()  () )  ( 13  ()  () ) )

So, when i add a new node to the tree i need to print this,

`(new node(left)(right))`

I try to do this, but my code only print the root, and not the nodes, like this:

( 11  ()  () )

( 11  ( 11  ()  () )  () )

( 11  ( 11  ()  () )  ( 11  ()  () ) )

I hope you can help me.

```
class No():
    def __init__(self, dado):
        self.dado = dado
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class ArvoreBinariaBusca():
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = None

    def Inserir(self, dado, raiz_atual):
        if self.raiz is None:
            self.raiz = No(dado)
            return

        if dado <= raiz_atual.dado:
            if raiz_atual.left is None:
                raiz_atual.left = No(dado)
            else:
                self.Inserir(dado, raiz_atual.left)
        else:
            if raiz_atual.right is None:
                raiz_atual.right = No(dado)
            else:
                self.Inserir(dado, raiz_atual.right)

    def printArvore(self, raiz):
        if raiz is None:
            return
        if raiz.left:
            no_esquerda = self.printArvore(raiz.left)
        else:
            no_esquerda = {}

        if raiz.right:
            no_direita = self.printArvore(raiz.right)
        else:
            no_direita = {}

        return '( {} {} {})'.format(self.raiz.dado, no_esquerda, no_direita)o

a = ArvoreBinariaBusca()
a.Inserir(11, a.raiz)
a.Inserir(2, a.raiz)
a.Inserir(13, a.raiz)
a.Inserir(4, a.raiz)
a.Inserir(15, a.raiz)
print(a.printArvore(a.raiz))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the last line of your *printArvore()* function:

```
return '( {} {} {})'.format(self.raiz.dado, no_esquerda, no_direita)
```

You always return the root of your *self*, meaning the root of the entire BinarySearchTree.

To solve this just remove the 'self':

```
return '( {} {} {})'.format(raiz.dado, no_esquerda, no_direita)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the solution in generic way, you can modify the code and names of classes, methods and variables as per your convenience.

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeft(self, node):
        if self.leftChild is None:
            self.leftChild = BinaryTree(node)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(node)
            t.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = t

    def insertRight(self, node):
        if self.rightChild is None:
            self.rightChild = BinaryTree(node)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(node)
            t.rightChild = self.rightChild
            self.rightChild = t

    def getRootValue(self):
        return self.root

    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

bt = BinaryTree(11)
bt.insertLeft(2)
bt.insertRight(13)
print(bt.getRootValue())
print(bt.getLeftChild().getRootValue())
print(bt.getRightChild().getRootValue())
```

Output:

```
11
2
13
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: This is an incorrect implementation of a BinarySearchTree and doesn't answer the question at all. Insertion needs to be done recursively, as in @DouglasNickson implementation.